# Настройка подсветки выделенной переменной во всем коде

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

При выделении переменной в визуал студио 2010, не выделяется она же во всём коде.

Как настроить визуал студио 2010, чтобы при выделении слова оно выделялось во всех местах где оно ещё встречается?

Comment: Это вопрос никак не по C++, так что хорошо бы по крайней мере сменить метку на `visual c++`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Можете установить [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) для 2010-ой Студии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или более специализированное дополнение [Highlight all occurrences of selected word](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Встроенная поддержка подсветки появилась начиная с, кажется, Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: это расширение не может быть добавлено ни для одного из установленных продуктов. стоит  visual studio 2010 express c++